# Is it possible to switch from a "normal" IT career to an academic career?

Tags: phd, career-path, job

I have a long experience of working like a programmer in many companies, but I was always tending to research. Is looking for PhD position real for me? Is it like looking for a job and how is it different? Do they pay money for research at PhD position? :D

I was passing a lot of exams on my jobs, but have no publications at all.

Comment: Have you looked for similar questions here?

Comment: Depends on country and the exact position if it is paid, similar to job etc. In STEM subjects, full-time phd positions (the ones which takes as much time as a job away) are usually paid (rightly so).

Comment: Do you have any academic background? A BSc, for example?

Comment: In the US, most graduate students in STEM fields work as research assistants or teaching assistants for 20 hours per week and take courses and work on their theses in the remaining hours.  At the high end, a TA or RA stipend might pay you $40K per year (but they're often much lower)  This would probably be a significant drop in income from your current position.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler I have MSc in physics

Answer (score 1):

Its very possible - but it also depends upon your profile. If you have a bachelors already its very easy to do a masters with a thesis component and then move towards a PhD. Or maybe if you have a masters already you can look into a Mphil and then PhD.

Something similar